# Create NativeScript Plugin using IOS Static Library issue

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I have created .a static library (tested in Xcode for native ios project and Its working fine)
Now I am following this https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-plugin-seed  to create nativescript plugin using .a static framework.

Plugin structure
[image]

**module.modulemap** file is created by me and it's look like this

```
module libstaticlibrary {
    umbrella header "staticlibrary.h"
    export *
}
```

**staticlibrary.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface staticlibrary : NSObject
+ (NSString *)sayHello;
@end
```

**libstaticlibrary.d.ts** also created by me

```
declare class staticlibrary extends NSObject {

    static sayHello():string;

}
```

Then in **helloplugin.common.ts** I am trying to access **staticlibrary.sayHello()** method.

```
export class Utils {
  public static SUCCESS_MSG(): string {
    // let msg = `Your plugin is working on ${app.android ? 'Android' : 'iOS'}.`;
    let msg = staticlibrary.sayHello();

    setTimeout(() => {
      dialogs.alert(`${msg} For real. It's really working :)`).then(() => console.log(`Dialog closed.`));
    }, 2000);

    return msg;
  }
```

I am getting following error.

```
node_modules/nativescript-helloplugin/helloplugin.common.ts(21,15): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'staticlibrary'.
```

What is I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's just the TypeScript compiler error, you have to generate typings for your static library (refer [docs](https://docs.nativescript.org/runtimes/ios/how-to/Use-Native-Libraries) to know how) or just add this line at top of your file.

`declare var staticlibrary: any`

I see that you do have a  declaration file in your code snippet, if you want to use it you have to include it to your `references.d.ts` file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have run the TNS_TYPESCRIPT_DECLARATIONS_PATH="$(pwd)/typings" tns build ios --for-device command and include the staticlibrary.d.ts path in reference.d.ts. I am getting "no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/.../nativescript-helloplugin/demo/node_modules/nativescript-helloplugin/platforms/ios/include/libstaticlibrary'. Obviously I dont have such a file.

Comment: Rename the libstaticlibrary.a to staticlibrary.a worked for me.